How should I add these two pieces of code to nginx.conf?
How should I add these two pieces of code to nginx.conf?
code a:
fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;

fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

proxy_buffer_size 128k;

proxy_buffers 4 256k;

proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;

code b:
pagespeed on;

pagespeed FileCachePath /opt/bitnami/nginx/var/ngx_pagespeed_cache;

location ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+" { add_header "" ""; }

location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_static/" { }

location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon$" { }

I'm not very familiar with coding, so I would appreciate a complete code example.

